# 426 Upgrade required Unirest and express server

Tags: java, node.js, express, unirest

I've createad a simple post poc using express and trying to post something from Java program using unirest library.

I'm recieving 426 Upgrade required as the response from the server, If I post from postman it's working fine.

Kindly help

```
var express = require('express')
,   app = express()
;

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).send("hi")
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Java Side

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.post("http://localhost:3000")
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .field("parameter", "value")
                .field("foo", "bar")
                .asJson();
System.out.println(jsonResponse);
```

Response Headers
WebSocket++/0.7.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why node.js requires an upgrade while trying to run an application on the localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698061/why-node-js-requires-an-upgrade-while-trying-to-run-an-application-on-the-localh)

Comment: @RomanVottner, I'm trying the same on linux box. It's working fine.